# Is there a way to redirect syslog messages to stdout?

Tags: c, linux, syslog

I have an application that can run in two modes, either with a CLI, or as a daemon.

I am using `syslog()` for logging. However, when run in CLI mode I'd like all the logging, except those marked `LOG_DEBUG`, messages to be sent to the console instead of logged.

I have tried to use `setlogmask()`, but that doesn't seem to redirect to console.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK, FreeBSD's syslog allows redirecting through /etc/syslog.conf. Anyway, it is not a way you're looking for. I suggest to write function that will detects if you're running as CLI app or daemon and does what it should: write to console or to syslog.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments by  maverik,  I wrote a wrapper around syslog that determines whether to send the output to the log or console. Here it is in case anyone ever needs this.

```
void mylog (int level, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);

    if (remote)
    {
        vsyslog(level, format, args);
    }   
    else
    {
        if (level == LOG_DEBUG)
            vsyslog(level, format, args);
        else
            vprintf(format, args);
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: Call `va_end(args)` before returning from the function.

Answer (score 4):

As GNU-specific solution I would suggest using `openlog(NULL, LOG_PERROR, your_facility)`. Not customizable(just duplicate on stderr).